# Declare multiple public variables with same property

Tags: c#, variables

```
public String name
{
    get;
    set;
}

public String email
{
    get;
    set;
}

public String address
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Is there an easier way to declare multiple variables with same property under one accessibility like this?

Something like

```
public String name, email, address
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: Nope, there isn't. You can make them one-liners though, which is tidier and typically how they're written: `public string name { get; set; }`

Comment: Its not possible the way you mentioned afaik. You can make a class of related properties and use single access specifier for it object.

Comment: Yes there is a possibility. It's called `class` ;)

Comment: @ckruczek so how would you do it?

Comment: If you want a quick template write  prop and hit two tabs...

Comment: I think you need to take a quick tour on how oop and classes works.

Comment: You can simply declare public variable rather than property.

Answer (score 3):

You could package them together in a separate class and then use that as a property:

```
class Info
{
    public String name { get; set; }       
    public String email { get; set; }      
    public String address { get; set; }
}

class Person
{
    public Info info { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously it's not what you're after in terms of inlining, but it does present a cleaner option if `Info` is something you'd use in more than one place.  If you're not going to use that class anywhere else, then it's pointless.

Note, as an aside, that I'm using your conventions for capitalization of properties, but it's a "convention" to use Pascal case.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care for OOP and just want a bunch of strings collected in one variable you can do this with a simple [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) in your case. It would look like this.

```
var bunchOfStrings = new Tuple<String,String,String>(String.Empty,String.Empty,String.Empty);
Console.Writeline("{0},{1},{2}",bunchOfStrings.Item1
                               ,bunchOfStrings.Item2
                               ,bunchOfStrings.Item3);
```

But keep in mind, you hide information with this approach. The items are just numbered and you loose any connection to the semantic of the items.